# Normal equations issue

Tags: least-squares, extreme-value, convex

Let $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ be an overdetermined system, with $A$ being an $n \times m $ full-column rank rectangular matrix.

Are these minimization problems equivalent?
$$ 1) \;\underset{\mathbf{x}} {\mathop{\min }}\,{{\left\| A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b} \right\|}_{2}}$$ 
$$ 2)\; \underset{\mathbf{x}} {\mathop{\min }}\,({{\left\| A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b} \right\|}_{2}})^2 $$

---

I'm only familiar with the known OLS result which gives rise to the normal equation $\mathbf{x}_{ls}=(A^tA)^{-1}A^t\mathbf{b}$ obtained from $2)$ by expressing it as:
$\;  \underset{\mathbf{x}} {\mathop{\min }}\ (A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})^t (A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})$
and by imposing gradient to be zero.

I also think that both $1)$ and $2)$ share the convexity property because any "$p-norm$" is convex and a square of a convex non-negative function is still convex.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "equivalent"?  Since squaring non-negative numbers is a one-to-one (and order preserving) operation, obviously the solutions are in one-to-one correspondence: it suffices to solve either problem if all you need is the solution.  But that doesn't mean they can be solved in the same way or with equal efficiency.  What, then, are you trying to ask?

Comment: I was wondering how can I show with calculus that the solution for $1)$ is still $\mathbf{x}_{ls}=(A^t A)^{-1}A^t \mathbf{b} $. Is that sufficient to show $2)$ minimization and adding the "one-to-one" consideration you pointed out?

Comment: You don't need Calculus, because the relationship between the two is immediate from the observation I made.  Using Calculus would just obscure that basic fact.

Comment: If you do *not* square the $2$-norm, the normal equations are given by $$\frac{1}{\| \rm A x - b \|_2} \rm A^\top (\rm A x - b) = 0_n$$ which is problematic if the linear system $\rm A x = b$ is feasible. However, if $\rm A x = b$ is feasible, why use least-squares?

Comment: @Rodrigo Did you perhaps misread "overdetermined" as "underdetermined"?

Comment: @whuber Did I? How so?

Comment: @Rodrigo "Feasible" is the terminology of linear programming rather than least squares estimation.  It's such a special situation when $Ax=b$ in the overdetermined case that it's scarcely worth mentioning--and seems only to confuse the issue.  I was hoping you had simply misread the question.

Comment: @whuber I don't like the term "consistent system". And the term "feasible" does not have to be monopolized by optimization theory. The terms "underdetermined" and "overdetermined" are also used without much discipline, as some use it to denote linear systems with fat or tall matrices, respectively. It's a special case indeed, but dividing zero by zero is special enough.

Comment: Your terminological preferences are fine--I'm just trying to explain (as you requested) why your original comment could reasonably have been construed to mean you misread the question. BTW, the division by zero arises only through uncritical application of Calculus: more careful consideration will remind us that the square root function fails to be differentiable at zero.  Thus, (a) we would explicitly state $Ax-b\ne 0$ in the Normal equations and (b) the cases $Ax-b=0$ would *automatically* be included among the critical points.